# ASP.NET - Is there a max number of .aspx pages your app should have?

Tags: asp.net

I know an ASP.NET app can have as many `aspx` pages as you want but after hitting a certain number of them (over 100) should I consider a different design? Or, as the months/years go by do I just keep adding more and more pages to my app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a concept called batch compilation in Asp.net. By default the value is true and it comes into effect only when debug is false. In production when you have debug = false, all the files in one folder get compiled into 1 dll because of batch compilation. The number of files that can be batch compiled together is 1000.

Coming to your question.

1. If you have more number of files in 1 folder JIT compilation will take longer.
2. First request in a folder will seem a bit slower because of JIT compilation.

Hence you should neatly categorize your files into multiple folders. There is no such hardlimit to the number of files you can have.

Answer (score 0):

Organize it with folders.Ex:you can have user related files like edituser.aspx,userlist.aspx,viewuser.aspx etc in a folder called User.This way you can make your solution looks much cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the only restriction is the cost of upkeep. This doesn't sound like a very organized (or designed) app if you need so many pages unless you have a valid reason of why you will need that amount of aspx files.